# is there any site a layman can understand excess rain (floods) and earth warming

Tags: climate, climate-models

I am not a scientist but I am interested in the effects of global warming on the envirand would like to read more in a layman form.
I have read where global warming - hotter earth surface temperature and green house atmosphere effects have lead to increased evaporation, which lead to lower denser heavier clouds that cause heavier quicker rain that can result in flooding and flash flooding.
This seems to make sense and I after more scientific/theories like this that give environmental changes apart from icecap melting and sea level rises that are well explained in layman terms.

Comment: you can find a lot of good information here https://climate.nasa.gov/